# How to add permalink to widget in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add Outbrain widget to my Wordpress blog and the code is:

```
<div class="OUTBRAIN" data-src="DROP_PERMALINK_HERE" data-widget-id="XX_1" data-ob-template=“NameGoesHere”></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="http://widgets.outbrain.com/outbrain.js"></script>
```

The problem is if I add this into the single.php, I can easily do it using `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` in place of `DROP_PERMALINK_HERE`. But I want to add the widget as a Wordpress widget and the text widget in Wordpress allows only HTML and PHP won't run there. So what do I do?

Get the URL of the page through Javascript? Or is there a better way?

Kindly guide.

Comment: You should create a widget, it's really easy :)

Comment: You should be able to do that with a shortcode http://wptricks.net/added-permalinks-shortcode-on-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

> If you would like to run PHP code in wordpress text widget then you
>   have to paste below code in you active theme's functins.php file.

```
function php_execute_widget($html){
   if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){ 
      ob_start(); eval("?".">".$html);
      $html=ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
    }
  return $html;
 }
 add_filter('widget_text','php_execute_widget',100);
```

Comment: Thanks @sameer, I too found this piece of code online, but do you think there are any security concerns of using this code?

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely very easy to do.

All you need is a Header and Footer plugin. With this, you can add the Outbrain code (Widget) to your blog easily.
- Just paste the code in the post-tab of the header and footer.